# How to display mathematical equations in both Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios

I would like to develop an app for math users, but I am wondering how to display math formulas and signs on ios and android, thx.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to some latex based library.
For android you can go for [MathView](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView) and for iOS you can use [iosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath)